# Multi-tenant job repository in spring-batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, multi-tenant

My system supports multi-tenancy, until now every tenant had its own job repository (i.e. under a tenant specific schema).
Meaning “myJob” could be executed for tenant X and tenant Y and be shared without any risk.

When a job is executed it resolves all the parameters. The parameters are resolved based on the last execution of the same job (which includes a tenant Id).
I have barrow the approach from SimpleJobOperator.startNextInstance , which is used to lunch my jobs as well.

```
//Find the last execution
List<JobInstance> lastInstances = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(jobName, 0, 1); 
//get the parameters of the last execution
lastInstances.get(0).getJobParameters()
```

Now a new requirement was raised, all tenants should maintain the job repository sharing single db schema. This will break the solution above because we are not sure that the last instance belongs to the current tenant.
**A naïve solution approach would be:**

```
List<JobInstance> lastInstances = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(jobName,0,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
for (JobInstance jobInstance : instances) {
        if(jobInstance.getJobParameters().getString("TENANT_ID")
          .equals(currentTenant)){
            tenantLastJobInstance = jobInstance;
            break;
        }
}
```

This ugly and inefficient solution and I am trying to avoid the above.

The ideal solution would be that myJob will act as a template and actual job will be named 
based on the tenant e.g. some variant of myJob+TenantId (myJobX and myJobY).

- Any Ideas on how to implement such approach will be welcomed
- Any alternative approaches to create a multi tenant will be welcomed as well.

Comment: can you please share an example of your first approach ? i'm having issue in setting up tenant specific spring batch.

Comment: it seems there is no possibility to get job parameters directly from `JobInstance` object in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head (I haven't thought about this too much) I'd recommend extending SimpleJobExplorer and adding a custom method to query based on the tenant id.  While it takes you away from the "standard" implementation just a bit, it would be the easiest way to address the need IMHO.